# How to learn the back end of flight simulators?

Tags: flight-simulator

I am an engineering student very passionate about aviation and especially flight simulation. I want to know more about how a flight simulator is coded but unfortunately there's not much available on the internet. I want to learn the software aspect of it and would appreciate some help being a complete beginner.

If someone could assist me answering a few questions or having a discussion regarding what language to learn or what books to read, it would be of great help.

Thanks in advance!

Cheers!

Answer (score 8):

The most advanced open source flight simulator is currently [FlightGear](https://www.flightgear.org/). It doesn't fall too far short of its commercial brethren.

The repository is [hosted on SourceForge](https://sourceforge.net/projects/flightgear/), where you can download the entire codebase.
For documentation and discussion on how it works, see the [forum](https://forum.flightgear.org/viewforum.php?f=18) and the mailing lists.

Once you have questions regarding the codebase per se, especially regarding the technical implementation rather than the business end of the simulation, they are best asked on the forums or on the main [Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/) site. Aviation.SE mainly deals with the flying aspects and real-life aircraft.

Comment: Alright , thanks a lot for helping